# .NET Core API + MVC Core Client supported by RestSharp

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, restsharp

I have created .NET Core Web Api with JWT authentication. Now, I am in the middle of creating web app using MVC Core. In MVC project I have API client wrapper:

Interface:

```
public interface IWebApiService
{
    Task<T> AuthenticateAsync<T>(string userName);
    Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string action, string authToken);
    Task PutAsync<T>(string action, T data, string authToken);
    Task PostAsync<T>(string action, T data, string authToken);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class WebApiService : IWebApiService
    {
        private readonly WebApiSettings _webApiSettings;

        public WebApiService(WebApiSettings webApiSettings)
        {
            _webApiSettings = webApiSettings;
        }

        public async Task<T> AuthenticateAsync<T>(string userName)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(_webApiSettings.BaseUri);
            var request = new RestRequest("/Login", Method.POST)
            {
                RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
            };
            request.AddBody(new { UserName = userName });

            var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
            }

            throw new ApiException(response.StatusCode.ToString(), response.ErrorMessage);
        }

        public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string action, string authToken)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(_webApiSettings.BaseUri);
            var request = new RestRequest(action, Method.GET)
            {
                RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
            };

            request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {authToken}");

            var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
            }

            throw new ApiException(response.StatusCode.ToString(), response.ErrorMessage);
        }

        public Task PutAsync<T>(string action, T data, string authToken)
        {
            // TODO
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task PostAsync<T>(string action, T data, string authToken)
        {
            // TODO
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

MVC Login Controller:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebApiService _webApiService;

    public LoginController(IWebApiService webApiService)
    {
        _webApiService = webApiService;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string redirectUrl)
    {
        var user = User.Identity.Name;

        if(user == null)
            throw new WebInterfaceException("Invalid username.");

        var response = await _webApiService.AuthenticateAsync<JwtToken>(user);

        HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("Token", response);

        return Redirect(redirectUrl ?? "/Home/Index");
    }
}
```

I keep JWT object in session as I didn't find better solution for storing tokens in MVC Core.

Below example controller:

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebApiService _webApiService;

    public ExampleController(IWebApiService webApiService)
    {
        _webApiService = webApiService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Browse()
    {
        var jwtToken =  HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<JwtToken>("Token");

        if (jwtToken == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Get", "Login", new { redirectUrl = Request.Path});
        }

        var response = await _webApiService.GetAsync<IEnumerable<ExampleBrowseViewModel>>("/Examples", jwtToken.Token);

        return Json(response);
    }
}
```

My problem is that in every controller action I will have to check if token is not null. If it's null, I am redirecting to Login page where I am retrieving token from API and redirecting to originally requested page. I would like to have some token handler where so I will not repeat the same code over and over. Additionally in my JWT object I have token expiration time and I would like to refresh it once it will expire so user could continue sending requests to API.
Can you give me few advises so I could accomplish this?

Comment: You can use cookie auth on MVC side and have token added as a claim on authenticated user so that it can be extracted and used to make authenticated calls to the service.

Comment: @Nkosi - can you give me an example for MVC Core?

Comment: Check official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: @Nkosi Unfortunately the link you send me does not help. In which claim should I store token? I don't see any called Token.